# Spectral theorem for symmetric real tensors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues, matrix-theory, tensor, nonlinear-eigenvalue

*Is there a definition of eigenvalues that allows to use a spectral theorem?*

Let $\mathbf{T}$ be a real fully symmetric tensor of order $3$ and size $N$. Its components can be represented as $T_{ijk}\in \mathbb{R}$ for all $1\leq i,j,k\leq N$. By symmetric I mean that if I permute any indices the value stays the same:
\begin{equation}
T_{ijk}=T_{ikj}=\dots=T_{jki}
\end{equation}

Using the following definition of eigenvalues, let $x\in \mathbb{C}^N$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ such that:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{jk}^NT_{ijk}x_kx_j=\lambda x_i
\label{eq1}
\end{equation}
with the constraint that $\sum_i x_i^2=1$.

Under what conditions can I say that the trace of $\left(\frac{1}{w-T}\right)$ will be equivalent to $\sum_\alpha \left(\frac{1}{w-\lambda_\alpha}\right)$?

Alternatively, under what conditions can I say that for $f(T)$  we have $\mathbf{x}_\alpha f(T) \mathbf{x}_{\alpha}=f\left(\lambda_{\alpha}\right) \mathbf{x}_{\alpha}$, (provided that $f\left(\lambda_{\alpha}\right)$ exists) where $\mathbf{x}_\alpha$ is an eigenvector of $T$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_\alpha$?

Comment: How do you intend to interpret any $f(T)$ when $T$ is not a square matrix? You seem to be interpreting it as a rectangular matrix $T_{(i)(jk)}$ instead.

Comment: By saying of size $N$ I assumed all indices to run up to $N$, so informally we can see $T$ as a cube not a rectangle.

Comment: Either for a cube or a rectangle, there is no common meaning to $f(T)$ or $(w-T)^{-1}$, unless you came up with your own, but just forgot to include it in the question.

Comment: Ok, that makes perhaps my post too vague or ill defined. If there is no more feedback coming I will close/delete the post then.